# How to update a document in mongodb with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a value for MongoDB using NodeJS this is my code:

Controller.js

```
    updateProduct: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { params: { id } } = req;
            const { body } = req;
            if (!body || Object.keys(body).length === 0) {
                Response.ERROR(res, new createError.BadRequest());
            } else {
            let product = await ProductsService.updateP(id, body);
        }
            if (!product) {
                Response.ERROR(res, new createError.NotFound());
            
            } else {
                Response.SUCCSESS(res, 201, `Producto actualizado`, product);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            debug(error);
            Response.ERROR(res);
        }
    },
```

Services.js

```
const updateP = async (id, product) => {
    const collection = await Database(COLLECTION);
    return collection.updateOne({_id: new ObjectId(id)}, { $set: { ...product } })
    
};
```

DB

```
 "body": {
        "_id": "651cd5d91e3c20bda7cea881",
        "name": "shoes",
        "price": 359,
        "quantity": 10,
    }
```

I got this error:

`MongoServerError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'`

I have investigate and tried to change `...product` for `req.params.name`, but it doesn't work

I'd like to get something like that:

```
 "body": {
        "_id": "651cd5d91e3c20bda7cea881",
        "name": "Coca-cola",
        "price": 359,
        "quantity": 10,
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error you are encountering arises because MongoDB does not allow the modification of the `_id` field of a document once it has been created. It's an immutable field.

In your update function, you're trying to update the document using the spread operator (`...product`) which spreads all the fields, including `_id`, from product into the update object. This is why you're seeing the error.

To resolve the issue, you should remove the _id field from the product object before you attempt the update:

```js
const updateP = async (id, product) => {
    const collection = await Database(COLLECTION);
    const { _id, ...updateData } = product;  // Remove _id from product
    return collection.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, { $set: updateData });
};
```

By destructuring the product object in this way, you're essentially extracting the `_id` field and the remaining data (which doesn't include `_id`) is stored in `updateData`. This `updateData` object can then safely be used in the `$set` operator without attempting to modify the `_id` field.